# Фарисей, ханжа, лицемер, лицедей, ипокрит

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова

В чем разница в оттенках между словами? Когда какое нужно использовать?

**фарисей**

> Лицемер, ханжа.

**ханжа**

> Неискренний человек, прикрывающийся показной добродетельностью или
>   набожностью; лицемер.

**лицемер**

> Тот, кто прикрывает своё двуличие, неискренность и злонамеренность
>   притворной добродетелью.

**лицедей**

> Тот, кто, притворяясь, рисуясь, старается казаться не тем и не таким,
>   кто и каков есть в действительности; притворщик, актёр.

**ипокрит**, *устаревшее*

> Ханжа, лицемер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Фарисей** comes from the Bible ("Фарисеи, увидев это, сказали Ему: вот, ученики Твои делают, чего не должно делать в субботу." - Матф 12:2) and as such sounds extremely bookish. Similarly, **ипокрит** is Greek and seems to be very infrequent. *Национальный корпус русского языка* gives only two examples for this word:

> Единственные честные *ипокриты* ― актеры. Хазлит [М. А. Чехов. О технике актера (1945)]

and

> Тут описываются следующие изображения: 1) Жизнь истинного монаха; 2) Небесный путь спасения души; 3) Смерть лицемера (*ипокрита*); 4) Смерть праведника; 5) Смерть грешника; 6) Обманчивость времени земной жизни. [А. С. Уваров. Русская символика (1864-1874)].

**Ханжа** and **лицемер** are more common. Ханжество is always related to piousness, righteousness and (often sexual) mores (["сознат маскировке собств. неблаговидных желаний и поступков под заботу о нравств. чистоте и порядочности"](http://didacts.ru/dictionary/1041/word/hanzhestvo)), while лицемерие is a more general term.

Finally, the first and foremost meaning of **лицедей** is actor, and while лицедей can be used as a synonym to лицемер, it seems to be not very common.

Comment: В Библии фарисеи - религиозно-политическая группа, отличавшаяся фанатизмом и лицемерием в выполнении внешних правил благочестия.